# Properties dictionary for Events in the Google Wave Python API

Tags: python, events, google-wave

The Google Wave documentation contains the [Robot Events](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/extensions/robots/index.html), but doesn't list what values will be put into the properties dictionary. Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question and found some hints in the following Google group thread: http://groups.google.com/group/google-wave-api/browse_thread/thread/8d19dbcb6f2147cc

For now, I think the closest you can get to an answer to this question is Jason Salas' response: "the good news is that you can look in the logs that Google App Engine generates for your robot in your dashboard (choose Info from the drop-down menu under your application), and you can manually read the JSON string and get the "properties" content."

I guess we'll just have to wait until the API stabilizes and the documentation is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

They are listed in [API Reference documentation](http://wave-robot-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/index.html), in the `waveapi.events` module.

Here's the list:

```
WAVELET_BLIP_CREATED
WAVELET_BLIP_REMOVED
WAVELET_PARTICIPANTS_CHANGED
WAVELET_SELF_ADDED
WAVELET_SELF_REMOVED
WAVELET_TIMESTAMP_CHANGED
WAVELET_TITLE_CHANGED
WAVELET_VERSION_CHANGED
BLIP_CONTRIBUTORS_CHANGED
BLIP_DELETED
BLIP_SUBMITTED
BLIP_TIMESTAMP_CHANGED
BLIP_VERSION_CHANGED
DOCUMENT_CHANGED
FORM_BUTTON_CLICKED
```

Comment: As the poster said, these events are are listed in the Robot Events. His question was what values are put in the PROPERTIES dictionary for each event.

Comment: D'oh, you are correct. I didn't read the question carefully enough. I don't know why he accepted my answer.